# Does the alarm monitor the whole autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm, autoscaling

When I set up an alarm for an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group to scale up when CPU utilization is larger than 80%, will it calculate a mean CPU utilization value of all the instances in the group? Or it just randomly monitor one instance of the group?

Lots of code include the parameter “dimensions”, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon CloudWatch metric is calculated against *all instances in the Auto Scaling group*.

Thus, for a CPU Utilization metric, it will take the **average CPU Utilization of all instances in the Auto Scaling group**. If the average exceeds 80%, it will add additional instances (as defined in your scaling policy).

This means that some instances might be 100% and some might be 0%. It is only the average CPU Utilization of *all instances* that will trigger the alarm.

**Dimensions** are sub-categories of metrics. For example, an Amazon EC2 CPU Utilization metric will have dimensions for Instance ID, Instance Type and Auto Scaling Group. They allow metrics to be filtered to specific subsets rather than applying to all instances.

Comment: But how do the dimensions connect with an asg? When creating alarm, we use the policy name, so the metric is thus related to the asg using that policy. Is this thinking right? If I want an alarm to be alarm on when CPUUTILIZATION of the whole asg is larger than 80, do I need to add dimensions for an asg?

Comment: When creating an Alarm for an Auto Scaling group in the console, it has you select a metric that already has a dimension set for the given Auto Scaling group. You can, however, use any metric to trigger a scaling policy (but it might not work as you expect). See: [marbot - Combine CloudWatch metrics for Auto Scaling or to reduce costs](https://marbot.io/blog/cloudwatch-combined-metrics.html)